# Cómo acceder a las propiedades de un array que es hijo de un array JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tengo la siguiente funcion `$.ajax` para armar un arbol de checkboxes y quiero cargar los hijos sólo de los checks que están seleccionados.

```
var Datos; // almaceno el resultado en esta variable para utilizarlas más adelante.
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/views/usuarios/index.aspx/obtenerarbolautorizaciones',
    data: "{ 'jdatos': '" + JSON.stringify({ Usuario: usuario }) + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        Datos = null;
        if (data.d != '') {
            Datos = JSON.parse(data.d);
        }
        else
            showError(stringErrorConexion);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
        showError(stringErrorConexion);
    },
    async: false
});
```

Que me duevuelve lo siguiente:

```
Array(5)
-0:{key: "0f1", key_padre: "#", title: "sector0", id_tipo_trabajo: "", select: false }
    -children: (8)
        -0:{key: "0f10", key_padre: "0f1", title: "sector01", id_tipo_trabajo: "0f10", select: true }
        -1:{key: "0f11", key_padre: "0f1", title: "sector02", id_tipo_trabajo: "0f11", select: true }
        -2:{key: "0f12", key_padre: "0f1", title: "sector03", id_tipo_trabajo: "0f12", select: true }
        -3:{key: "0f13", key_padre: "0f1", title: "sector04", id_tipo_trabajo: "0f13", select: true }
        -4:{key: "0f14", key_padre: "0f1", title: "sector05", id_tipo_trabajo: "0f14", select: true }
        -5:{key: "0f15", key_padre: "0f1", title: "sector06", id_tipo_trabajo: "0f15", select: true }
        -6:{key: "0f16", key_padre: "0f1", title: "sector07", id_tipo_trabajo: "0f16", select: true }
        -7:{key: "0f17", key_padre: "0f1", title: "sector08", id_tipo_trabajo: "0f17", select: true }
-1:{key: "1f1", key_padre: "#", title: "sector1", id_tipo_trabajo: "", select: false }
    -children: (4)
        -0:{key: "1f10", key_padre: "1f1", title: "sector01", id_tipo_trabajo: "1f10", select: false }
        -1:{key: "1f11", key_padre: "1f1", title: "sector02", id_tipo_trabajo: "1f11", select: false }
        -2:{key: "1f12", key_padre: "1f1", title: "sector03", id_tipo_trabajo: "1f12", select: false }
        -3:{key: "1f13", key_padre: "1f1", title: "sector04", id_tipo_trabajo: "1f13", select: false }
        -4:{key: "1f14", key_padre: "1f1", title: "sector05", id_tipo_trabajo: "1f14", select: false }
-2:{key: "1f2", key_padre: "#", title: "sector2", id_tipo_trabajo: "", select: false }
-3:{key: "1f3", key_padre: "#", title: "sector3", id_tipo_trabajo: "", select: false }
-4:{key: "1f4", key_padre: "#", title: "sector4", id_tipo_trabajo: "", select: false }
```

Quiero saber cómo puedo obtener los `childrens` con la propiedad `select = true` (que indica que ese check está seleccionado) teniendo en cuenta que los hijos de los hijos también tienen la propiedad `select` y pueden tener valor `true` o `false`.

Se me ocurrió hacer un `filter` pero no sé como hacerlo con cada hijo (en el siguiente código recorro los padres)

```
function filtrarData(chkData) {
    if ('select' in chkData && typeof (chkData.select) === true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
dataAutorizaciones.filter(filtrarData);
```

**UPDATE**
En cada iteración, `chkData` es un padre. Por ejemplo en la primer iteración `chkData` tiene:

```
Object(8)
-children: (8)
    -0:{...}
    -1:{...}
    -2:{...}
    -3:{...}
    -4:{...}
    -5:{...}
    -6:{...}
    -7:{...}
```

Si a este código lo envuelvo en un `for` para recorrer `dataAutorizaciones` y tomar cada índice me indica que `chkData` es `undefined`.

Comment: que  valor tiene chkData??? y cuando te refieres a children? quienes serian los hijos??? puedes usar selectores avanzado `#padre > input[type="check"] ` o publica el html y lo que deseas como resultado!

Comment: chkData toma el valor de cada padre para hacer la iteración y children sí, me refiero a los hijos (dejo el ejemplo de chkdata en el código). No dejé el HTML porque se generan dinamicamente y a esta altura del código todavía no está renderizado, sólo es un ``span`` con una clase ``dynatree-checkbox``

Comment: Puedes poner el objeto "Datos" en formato json para ver cual es la estructura que obtienes en el lado cliente.

Comment: ``Datos`` tiene la estructura que dejé debajo de la función ``$.ajax,`` el array de 5 posiciones

Answer (score 0):

```js
//ASUMIENDO QUE ESTA ES LA ESTRUCTURA QUE TE RETORNA DEL BACKEND

data = [{
    key: "0f1",
    key_padre: "#",
    title: "sector0",
    id_tipo_trabajo: "",
    select: false,
    hijos: [{ key: "0f10", key_padre: "0f1", title: "sector01", id_tipo_trabajo: "0f10", select: true },
            { key: "0f11", key_padre: "0f1", title: "sector02", id_tipo_trabajo: "0f11", select: true },
            { key: "0f12", key_padre: "0f1", title: "sector03", id_tipo_trabajo: "0f12", select: true },
            { key: "0f13", key_padre: "0f1", title: "sector04", id_tipo_trabajo: "0f13", select: true },
            { key: "0f14", key_padre: "0f1", title: "sector05", id_tipo_trabajo: "0f14", select: true },
            { key: "0f15", key_padre: "0f1", title: "sector06", id_tipo_trabajo: "0f15", select: true },
            { key: "0f16", key_padre: "0f1", title: "sector07", id_tipo_trabajo: "0f16", select: true },
            { key: "0f17", key_padre: "0f1", title: "sector08", id_tipo_trabajo: "0f17", select: true }]
},
{
    key: "1f1",
    key_padre: "#",
    title: "sector1",
    id_tipo_trabajo: "",
    select: false,
    hijos: [{ key: "1f10", key_padre: "1f1", title: "sector01", id_tipo_trabajo: "1f10", select: true },
            { key: "1f11", key_padre: "1f1", title: "sector02", id_tipo_trabajo: "1f11", select: false },
            { key: "1f12", key_padre: "1f1", title: "sector03", id_tipo_trabajo: "1f12", select: false },
            { key: "1f13", key_padre: "1f1", title: "sector04", id_tipo_trabajo: "1f13", select: false },
            { key: "1f14", key_padre: "1f1", title: "sector05", id_tipo_trabajo: "1f14", select: false }
    ]
},
{
    key: "1f2",
    key_padre: "#",
    title: "sector2",
    id_tipo_trabajo: "",
    select: false
},
{
    key: "1f3",
    key_padre: "#",
    title: "sector3",
    id_tipo_trabajo: "",
    select: false
},
{
    key: "1f4",
    key_padre: "#",
    title: "sector4",
    id_tipo_trabajo: "",
    select: false
}
];

//ESTA SERÍA LA SOLUCIÓN.
let hijosTrue=[];
// obtener únicamente registros con hijos
let conHijos = data.filter(obj => obj.hijos);

conHijos.map(x => {
   x.hijos.map(y=>{ if(y.select){hijosTrue.push(y)}});    
} )
console.log(hijosTrue)
```

Comment: Se acerca bastante a lo que busco pero no puedo confirmarlo todavía porque no sé por qué me da "Error de sintaxis" en la expresión lambda tanto en ``obj => obj.hijos`` como en el ``map``

Comment: Es muy probable que falle porque no todos los nodos tienen hijos. Estas intentado buscar el atributo hijo en un objeto que no tiene y te salta el error. Tendrías que crear una validación previa para saber si tiene hijo o no antes de iterar. En mi ejemplo yo lo hago en dos tiempos. Primero extraigo todos los que tiene hijos y luego hago las iteraciones. Saludos

Comment: Si, eso lo veo y lo puedo arreglar pero lo que no entiendo es por qué el ``.js`` me da ese error de sintaxis, es como que no reconoce o no acepta las funciones flecha lo cual me parece extraño porque ya las he utilizado anetriormente (no en este proycto) sin problemas.